# Gaming Fall 2011 Grant Results

Tags: discussion, promotional-grant

As per [this Meta announcement](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2952/cleaning-up-the-game-promotion-grants), the Fall 2011 Gaming Grant application process has come to... a bit of an abrupt end.

As Brett, who was running it, cannot actually see deleted posts, this is simply an archive thread meant to post out who *did* get listed.

Each game will be listed as its own answer, with all of the applicants listed afterwards. I will only be listing the top 10 in the event that there were more than 10 applicants for any particular game, using the original top reputation metric from the original run.

---

All 9 games for the session have been posted. Please double-check your entry and if something is erroneous or if there is something you think you should add, feel free to edit it right in (or comment me, if you are sub 2k). I'll have Brett mark each post if the games have been ordered.

Comment: Wouldn't locking and temporarily undeleting the [meta-tag:promotional-grant] questions be easier? I mean, this way we're losing all the comments in the entries, on the entries and on the opening posts -- about distributors, pre-order bonuses, specific editions of the games, etc. Also, I recall Cyberskull and yx. entering for 3 games, so that'll have to be resolved.

Comment: I'm including extra data where necessary and when stated. Locked or not, undeleting all 9 posts isn't going to be a very amiable act.

Comment: @lunboks: comments for [Elder scrolls](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/2869/comments), [Battlefield](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/2870/comments), [Batman](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/2871/comments) are viewable (click the links). The rest did not appear to have any comments.

Comment: My preferred options went in this order: Skyrim - Batman - Zelda (I signed up for zelda as a third option since I was in the 9th spot for Skyrim and I might be bumped out of it).  So someone else can move up and take the zelda spot if I do, in fact, make it onto the Skyrim list.

Comment: So, about this round, since a new one has started... Is this being done according to the new reimbursement rules or not? Should I contact someone (and who? Is Brett still in charge?), or will someone contact me?

Comment: @lunboks Brett is still running this the same as before, I believe.

Comment: @lunboks After being informed of my error, I withdrew the 3rd entry.

Answer (score 3):

The game in this thread is **The Legend of Zelda: Skyward Sword**. It is available for **Wii**. It will be released on **November 20th, 2011**.

There were 11 applicants, so only the **top 10** were taken.

> [DMA57361](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1485/dma57361)
>
> Platform: **Wii (PAL)**
>
> Extra Note: Extra Wiimote would be nice, if everyone else is getting it.

---

> [Ronan Forman](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4012/ronan-forman)
>
> Platform: **Wii (PAL)**
>
> Extra Note: [This](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002I0GEHI) version is preferred.

---

> [lunboks](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/9752/lunboks)
>
> Platform: **Wii (PAL)**
>
> Extra Note: Gold Remote/Limited Edition deal would be neat.

---

> [CyberSkull](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/9300/cyberskull)
>
> Platform: **Wii**
>
> Extra Note: [Gold Remote Bundle](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002I0GEHI) requested

---

> [Powerlord](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2974/powerlord)
>
> Platform: **Wii**

---

> [jsnlxndrlv](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11689/jsnlxndrlv)
>
> Platform: **Wii**
>
> Extra Note: Preferably [bundled](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002I0GEHI).

---

> [Ullallulloo](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/118/ullallulloo)
>
> Platform: **Wii**
>
> Extra Note: Gold Bundle would be nice

---

> [Nick](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1070/nick)
>
> Platform: **Wii**

---

> [Kevin YouAreABird](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/18/kevin-y)
>
> Platform: **Wii**

---

> [Matthew Read](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/6066/matthew-read)
>
> Platform: **Wii**
>
> Extra Note: `http://www.amazon.ca/dp/B002BSC54I` would be best.

Comment: Yay, IAmABird. ♪

Answer (score 2):

The game in this answer is **Batman: Arkham City**. It is available for **PC, PS3 and Xbox 360**. Please correct me if I am missing any systems. It will be released on **October 18th, 2011**.

There were **10** applicants, a full house!

> [NickT](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2259/nick-t)
>
> Platform: **PC via Steam**

---

> [murgatroid99](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1787/murgatroid99)
>
> Platform: **PC via Steam**

---

> [mordi2k](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5521/mordi2k)
>
> Platform: **PC via Steam**

---

> [CyberSkull](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/9300/cyberskull)
>
> Platform: **360**

---

> [Neighboring Community's Invading Regime Dictator](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1925/anna-lear)
>
> Platform: **360**

---

> [Ullallulloo](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/118/ullallulloo)
>
> Platform: **PS3**

---

> [yx.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3917/yx)
>
> Platform: **PC via Steam**

---

> [FallenAngelEyes](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/160/fallenangeleyes)
>
> Platform: **PS3**
>
> Extra Note: [Collector's Edition](http://www.game.co.uk/en/batman-arkham-city-collectors-edition-143298) is preferable if possible, in Europe so US Amazon is probably expensive.

---

> [Matthew Read](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/6066/matthew-read)
>
> Platform: **360**
>
> Extra Note: Best through Amazon Canada ( `http://www.amazon.ca/dp/B004ELB2U8` )

---

> [Dave McClelland](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4775/dave-mcclelland)
>
> Platform: **PC via Steam**

Comment: I'd actually prefer Steam - is editing the answer all I have to do to make that correction, or should I contact Brett?

Comment: PC version was delayed into November.

Comment: `>:(`  It seems like more people play those games on consoles, so now this puts me and my Winbox way behind to try to capture the early flurry of questions.

Comment: @DaveMcClelland I'd think he's going to contact us?  The game comes out tomorrow (for non-PC) so I'm surprised he hasn't already, actually.

Comment: @MatthewRead Good question.  Brett already has my contact information, so I didn't think much of it.  Assuming it's acceptable, though, I'd rather just wait until November for the PC release (darn delays :()

Answer (score 1):

The game in this answer is **Lego Harry Potter: Years 5-7**. It is available for **PC, PS3, Wii and NDS**. The game is released on **November 11th, 2011**.

There were **3** applicants.

> [Ben Blank](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1980/ben-blank)
>
> Platform: **360**, because it's actually out for a lot more platforms than listed

---

> [Ashley Nunn](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11502/ashley-nunn)
>
> Platform: **NDS**

---

> [Jason Berkan](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1057/jason-berkan)
>
> Platform: **PS3**

Answer (score 1):

The game in this answer is **Torchlight 2**. It is available for **PC**.

NOTE: Torchlight 2 **does not yet have a release date**. It is possible that it will be pushed to 2012. In the event of this happening, users will receive the game in 2012 and will be able to apply to any one game in the Fall 2011 Grant that still has open slots available. I cannot, however, guarantee that any of the other 8 games will still have open slots in the event of Torchlight 2 being pushed to 2012. It's a risky, risky world, these video games!

There were **9** applicants.

> [mordi2k](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/5521/mordi2k)
>
> Platform: **Windows via Steam**

---

> [bummzack](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5433/bummzack)
>
> Platform: **Mac via Steam**

---

> [Mr. November](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1155/mr-november)
>
> Platform: **Windows via Steam**

---

> [Arda Xi](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/56/arda-xi)
>
> Platform: **Windows via Steam**

---

> [That one blue ninja dude, who might be badp](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/23/badp)
>
> Platform: **Steam**

---

> [Brant](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/274/brant)
>
> Platform: **Mac (Windows if must) via Steam**

---

> [C. Ross](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/121/c-ross)
>
> Platform: **Windows via Steam**

---

> [Sathya](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/200/sathya)
>
> Platform: **Windows via Steam**

---

> [Mark Trapp](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3389/mark-trapp)
>
> Platform: **Mac via Steam**

Comment: Torchlight II has been [pushed back to 2012](http://www.torchlight2game.com/news/2011/11/17/an-update-from-travis-baldree/).

Answer (score 1):

The game in this answer is **Might and Magic: Heroes VI**. It is available for **PC and Steam**. It will be released on **October 11th, 2011**.

There are **5** applicants.

> [No Longer Player 2](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/336/raven-dreamer)
>
> Platform: **PC via Steam**

---

> [Jupotter](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11089/jupotter)
>
> Platform: **PC via Steam**

---

> [Dave DuPlantis](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8366/dave-duplantis)
>
> Platform: **PC via Steam**

---

> [bwarner](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/341/bwarner)
>
> Platform: **PC via Steam**

---

> [Jason Berkan](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1057/jason-berkan)
>
> Platform: **PC via Steam**

Answer (score 1):

The game in this answer is **The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim**. It is available for **PC, PS3, Steam and Xbox 360**. It will be released on **November 11th, 2011**.

There were **13** applicants, so only the top 10 will be listed.

> [Fabian](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4103/fabian)
>
> Platform: **PC via Steam**

---

> [Drake](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/730/drake)
>
> Platform: **PC via Steam**

---

> [DMA57361](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1485/dma57361)
>
> Platform: **PC via Steam**

---

> [Raven Dreamer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/336/raven-dreamer)
>
> Platform: **PC**

---

> [StrixVaria](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1719/strixvaria)
>
> Platform: **360**

---

> [bwarner](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/341/bwarner)
>
> Platform: **PC via Steam**

---

> [LessPop_MoreFizz](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3129/lesspop-morefizz)
>
> Platform: **PC (possibly) via Steam**

---

> [Maaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaana](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/207/mana)
>
> Platform: **PC via Steam**

---

> [yx.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3917/yx)
>
> Platform: **PC via Steam**

---

> [Mark Trapp](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3389/mark-trapp)
>
> Platform: **PS3**

Comment: No steam is probably not possible, so I think you should edit that bit out.

Answer (score 1):

The game in this answer is **Saints Row: The Third**. It is available for **PC, PS3, Steam and Xbox 360**. The game is released on **November 15th, 2011**.

There were **3** applicants.

> [jsnlxndrlv](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11689/jsnlxndrlv)
>
> Platform: PS3
>
> Extra Note: Must be US compatible.

---

> [One Of The Daves With A PreSummat Style Surname](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8366/dave-duplantis)
>
> Platform: 360
>
> Extra Note: In the US, recommend buying through Amazon and getting the Professor Genki DLC.

---

> [FallenAngelEyes](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/160/fallenangeleyes)
>
> Platform: 360
>
> Extra Note: Wants [Professor Genki Edition](http://www.game.co.uk/en/saints-row-the-third-professor-genki-edition-141301). Must be bought compatible for EU console, may go reimbursement route.

Answer (score 0):

The game in this answer is **Assassin's Creed Revelations**. It is available for **PC, PS3 and Xbox 360**. The game is released on **November 30th, 2011**.

There were **7** applicants.

> [jupotter](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11089/jupotter)
>
> Platform: **PC via Steam**

---

> [sjohnston](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/816/sjohnston)
>
> Platform: **PC via Steam**

---

> [Ivo Flipse](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10/ivo-flipse)
>
> Platform: **PS3**

---

> [Our Founder](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14/juan-manuel)
>
> Platform: **PC via Steam**

---

> [Jeff Mercado](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8995/jeff-mercado)
>
> Platform: **PC**

---

> [Resorath](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4393/resorath)
>
> Platform: **360**

---

> [Dave McClelland](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4775/dave-mcclelland)
>
> Platform: **PC via Steam**

Comment: I was sad when I didn't see my name, I thought I wasn't eligible for participating or something :)

Comment: Steam is a viable option for me if it's easier/cheaper than shipping a disk.

Comment: I'd actually prefer Steam - is editing the answer all I have to do to make that correction, or should I contact Brett?

Comment: @Dave It's fine to just edit it in here. November 30th is quite a ways away.

Comment: @GraceNote: How soon will we receive notices or can we ask about about the games?  There are some preorder perks that I wouldn't mind getting (or not) but I imagine we'd have to order beforehand.

Comment: @Jeff Poke Brett to see if he's up for being able to order early for this one.

Comment: Grace, this is [available for pre-purchase on steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/201870), there are even bonuses for doing so. It'd be cool if you start sending them now even though it's not released yet. edit: 'now' as in 'for taking advantage of the pre-purchase bonus'

Comment: @JuanManuel: It's too bad there isn't one set of pre-order goodies for all retailers.  It seems to vary everywhere I've looked.  [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/201870/) has the Ottoman Doctor (MP?), [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Assassins-Creed-Revelations-Pc/dp/B002I0IHIM) has the "Altair Outfit" (SP), and [GameStop](http://www.gamestop.com/collection/assassins-creed-revelations) has a bunch more including the Ottoman Jester (MP), Vlad Prison, and various upgrades and goodies.  I'm starting to think I should go for the GS route to get the most out of this.

Comment: Bit the bullet and preordered this instead.  I guess I'll have to contact Brett to give him a scan of my receipt.

Comment: @GraceNote: Sorry to bug you about this again but could you poke Brett for me?  I'm trying to get a hold of him without sticking comments on unrelated posts and so far have been unsuccessful.  Or perhaps a process for communication needs to be solidified for all grants.  You guys know how to contact us but we don't really know how to contact you guys back.

Comment: @Jeff I'll see what I can find out

Comment: @GraceNote Can you check with Brett on this for me?  Now that it's out for consoles, I thought Brett may contact me about a Steam preorder but haven't heard anything about it.  He and you both should have my email address.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The game in this answer is **Battlefield 3**. It is available for **PC, PS3 and Xbox 360**. The game is released on **October 25th, 2011**.

There were **3** applicants. Sorta.

> [Mana](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/207/mana)
>
> Platform: **PC via Origin**

---

> [lunboks](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/9752/lunboks)
>
> Platform: **PC**
>
> Extra Note: Limited Edition via Amazon would be great

---

> [That warbly brown-haired fellow what can't spell](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/821/thomas-mcdonald)
>
> Platform: **PC via Origin**

Comment: I don't really care how, though. I mean, I'm not sure whether Origin supports buying copies for other people, but if it does, it's just as well. Better, even. No shipping and suchlike.