# Torchlight 2 Game Grant

Tags: support, promotional-grant

Now that Torchlight 2 has a release date of September 20th, when can we expect to hear about the game grant [from about a year ago](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2964/1155)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grace has just noted that **yes, the game grant will take place**, although [it will still take a few days to get everything sorted out](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6225055#6225055) because <s>someone has been clogging the Internet pipes</s> this question managed to slip through the cracks.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for helping pursue this :)

Comment: So, I take it this isn't happening? It's not that big a deal, probably mildly disappointing at best, but I just want to confirm. It'd probably be a waste of resources this late after release.